# Blackberry webworks focus issue

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I am working on blackberry webworks project, in which using focus based navigation.

Now my problem is i have focus on one button and by clicking that button i am calling ajax which in turn loads new html for another page and loads it to specified div.

Now i need to  set focus to one of elements in the loaded html but it not working and focus is still on last focused element.

Waiting for solution.

Answer (score 1):

The focus mode event handlers that are assigned to page elements are injected when the page is first loaded (HTTP request), not after each subsequent DOM change (whether it is via AJAX or direct JavaScript).

Here is the official documentation about focus mode navigation:
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/using_the_navigation_mode_1866978_11.html

Suggest using appendChild() to add DOM elements to the page, instead of innerHTML = "", and then seeing if those newly-added elements have focus events.